# DB design for SO-like message and how to query?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm assuming that StackOverflow's question and answer (or even FB's wall messages) can be mimicked by the following model:

```
TABLE: message

==================================================================
| message_id | parent_message_id | message           | timestamp |
==================================================================
| 1          | 0                 | Hi                | 100       |
| 2          | 1                 | hello             | 200       |
| 3          | 1                 | hello back to you | 300       |
| 4          | 0                 | How are you?      | 150       |
| 5          | 4                 | Good. You?        | 200       |
| 6          | 4                 | Good, too.        | 250       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a good way to do parent-child relationships for such messages? It could be split into 2 tables, but the child table would look exactly like the parent table + a foreign key. So I think one table is good enough.
2. How do I query: get a list of all parent messages and the first 4 responses to them?
3. How do I query: given a parent message id, get a list of the next 10 responses after the first 4?
4. How do I query: get the last 10 messages of a particular discussion thread (similar to FB's messages where you only see the last x-number of messages)?
5. How do I query: get the second to the last 10 messages of a particular discussion thread (again, similar to FB's messages when you scroll up and it shows you more of the previous messages)?

If the DB design concept is inherently wrong, please let me know.

Comment: How about showing us your own attempts?

Comment: I'm not even sure if the model is the right way to go. Also, I'm not sure how to query it myself.

Comment: You can have a look at SO's database layout here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new  **The tables and fields are on the right**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the DB layout for SO.
As you can see in the first table `posts` your idea is exactly what SO does.

A query to get a question and its answers would be:

```
  SELECT q.body, q.otherfields
  FROM posts q
  WHERE q.id = 1234
UNION ALL
  SELECT a.body, a.otherfields
  FROM posts a
  WHERE a.ParentId = 1234
```

This will put the question at the top and the answers below it.

Stackoverflow data structure:

```
Posts
    Id
    PostTypeId
    AcceptedAnswerId
    ParentId
    CreationDate
    Score
    ViewCount
    Body
    OwnerUserId
    OwnerDisplayName
    LastEditorUserId
    LastEditorDisplayName
    LastEditDate
    LastActivityDate
    Title
    Tags
    AnswerCount
    CommentCount
    FavoriteCount
    ClosedDate
    CommunityOwnedDate
Users
    Id
    Reputation
    CreationDate
    DisplayName
    LastAccessDate
    WebsiteUrl
    Location
    AboutMe
    Views
    UpVotes
    DownVotes
    EmailHash
    Age
Comments
    Id
    PostId
    Score
    Text
    CreationDate
    UserDisplayName
    UserId
Badges
    Id
    UserId
    Name
    Date
PostFeedback
    Id
    PostId
    IsAnonymous
    VoteTypeId
    CreationDate
PostHistory
    Id
    PostHistoryTypeId
    PostId
    RevisionGUID
    CreationDate
    UserId
    UserDisplayName
    Comment
    Text
PostHistoryTypes
    Id
    Name
PostTags
    PostId
    TagId
PostTypes
    Id
    Name
SuggestedEdits
    Id
    PostId
    CreationDate
    ApprovalDate
    RejectionDate
    OwnerUserId
    Comment
    Text
    Title
    Tags
    RevisionGUID
SuggestedEditVotes
    Id
    SuggestedEditId
    UserId
    VoteTypeId
    CreationDate
    TargetUserId
    TargetRepChange
Tags
    Id
    TagName
    Count
TagSynonyms
    Id
    SourceTagName
    TargetTagName
    CreationDate
    OwnerUserId
    AutoRenameCount
    LastAutoRename
    Score
    ApprovedByUserId
    ApprovalDate
Votes
    Id
    PostId
    VoteTypeId
    UserId
    CreationDate
    BountyAmount
VoteTypes
    Id
    Name
```

Comment: Johan, what about getting only the first x-number of responses? Or the last y-number of responses?